# PowerShell: Check if Variable is smaller than 15.0.0.152

Tags: powershell

How can I test which version number is bigger?

```
$Variable1:15.0.0.152
$Variable2:15.0.1.153
```

If want to write a simple if question like `($Variable1 -gt $Variable2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the best solution, but you could try this:

```
[int]($Variable1.Split('.') -Join '') -gt [int]($Variable2.Split('.') -Join '')
```

UPDATE! This is what you want:

```
[System.Version]$Version = "15.0.0.15"
[System.Version]$Version2 = "15.0.1.15"
$Version -gt $Version2
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply, but it doesn't work as expected.    $variable1="15.0.0.15"
$Variable2="15.0.1.5"
[int]($Variable1.Split('.') -Join '') -gt [int]($Variable2.Split('.') -Join '')
True

Comment: Yes, that's why this way is not really any good. As it just "converts" the version number into an integer and compares them. In this example that would be 150015 and 15015. So the comparison returning true is actually correct, but not what you want.

Comment: Updated my answer with a better way.

Comment: Great! Sometimes it can be so easy!! :)